# Issue when compiling Cython code with more than 1000 global constants

Tags: python, visual-c++, cython

Let's say `test.py` has many constant definitions (use case: coming from an API):

```
CONSTANT0 = 0
CONSTANT1 = 1
CONSTANT2 = 2
...
CONSTANT3998 = 3998
CONSTANT3999 = 3999
```

Now building this with Cython on Windows:

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup     # will use my default compiler MSVC++
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize("test.py", language_level="3"), script_args=['build'])
```

**takes many minutes, and never finishes.**

I see in task manager that `link.exe` takes 25% of my CPU during minutes, and the memory usage increases: 800 MB at the time I'm writing this!

How to solve this little Cython bug?

---

You can generate a dummy module `test.py` with 4000 constants with this code:

```
with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(1000):
        f.write(f'CONSTANT{i} = {i}\n')
```

Comment: Well you should definitely report this to their issues page or at least search it, seems like someone would've encountered this before https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: Good idea, I did it [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4924) @RandomDavis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by removing the compiler optimizations, as seen in [this issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4924).

The compiler parameter `/Od` seems to be necessary:

```
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension('test', sources=['test.py'], extra_compile_args=['/Od'])),
    script_args=['build'])
```

Comment: I think you should self-accept this answer